# Use only available timestamps as ticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I try to plot some data using the following function:

```
def plotData(scores, dates):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   ax.plot_date(dates, scores, '-')
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
   ax.xaxis.set_ticks(dates)

   plt.show()
```

scores and dates are both Pandas series where scores consists of floats and dates are Python's datetime objects (both contains some NaNs, too).

I want the plot to show only the days in dates as ticks. However, the line

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(dates)
```

causes the following error:

```
File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1103, in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas/tslib.c:20491)
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'
```

If I remove this line the data is correctly plotted but it shows ticks at days where no recording is available since it just interpolates the period between the first and the last recording.

Comment: It might help to use [`matplotlib.dates.date2num()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) to set the ticks numerically.

Comment: Thank you, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! `ax.xaxis.set_ticks(date2num(dates.dropna()))` does exactly what I need!